# Android: Function not working in Thread but works otherwise (trying to add ProgressDialog)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, methods, progressdialog

So I have a little app I am working on that scrapes comics from the web and displays them on my phone.  Nothing fancy, just using it to learn the ropes.  The function called comicReload(); does most of the work and it is called many times in the application (on first run, and when the user clicks certain buttons.  Here is the function:

```
public void comicReload () throws IOException {
    //clears some Vectors that have things in them from the last run
    imagetitles.clear();
    imagetext.clear();
    imagelinks.clear();

    //forms the link it will connect to, and connects
    connector = siteBase + Integer.toString(comicNumber);
    doc = Jsoup.connect(connector).get();
    media = doc.select("[src]");

    //gets the required media from the site
    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img"));
            imagetitles.add(src.attr("alt"));
            imagetext.add(src.attr("title"));
            imagelinks.add(src.attr("src"));
    }

    //some variables I could probably get rid of, but it's easy to read
    Integer titlesize = imagetitles.size();
    Integer textsize = imagetext.size();
    Integer linkssize = imagelinks.size();

    comicTitle = (imagetitles.get(titlesize-4));
    hoverText = (imagetext.get(textsize-4));
    comicLink = (imagelinks.get(linkssize-4));

    //gets the picture I am looking for along with the associated text
    URL url = new URL(comicLink);
    InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
    image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

    //finally puts the scraped information into the layout
    comicView.setImageDrawable(image);
    title.setText(comicTitle);
    htext.setText(hoverText);
}
```

It works 100% fine when it is called, but it's a little slow over 3G so I tried to add a ProgressDialog to show while it loads.  This is my attempt (this is the code that runs where I used to just have comicReload();)

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Getting Comic", "Loading", true, false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {  
           public void run() {
               try {
                   comicReload();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.i("ComicReloadFail","Sam");
               }
               pd.dismiss();
               return;
           }
    }).start();
```

The Thread itself runs fine, and when I put some random code to execute in place of the try-catch block with the comicReload(); in it everything goes dandy.  The second I put the comicReload() back in there, however, running the app causes the ProgressDialog spinner to spin for a few seconds before the app force closes.  What is causing this?  And why does comicReload() stop working when it's in a thread.  I just want a way to execute that method with a spinner going while it works.

Thanks in advance guys, I know that was a lot to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do UI related updates in a different thread than the one that created the UI.

try using Handler

```
public static final Handler handlerVisibility = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int visibility = msg.getData().getInt("visibility");
        view.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry I might not have been clear, what you do with this is place it in your main UI thread(usually the Activity), this way you can send a message from your thread that does the update to the UI thread and the changes should be taken in account because they are considered as coming form the UI thread

Comment: Even though I don't know enough to fully understand what you said, you gave me enough info to use Google and get it working.  So a green check and a thank you for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything UI-related in a worker thread. You'll need to do that on the UI thread. There are easy ways to do that - you can call `Activity.runOnUiThread()`, for example.

Comment: How exactly do I use this, and will it still allow the ProgressDialog to show?  After all, that's what this was about for me.

Comment: Easiest way - keep your code the way it is, but anything that does anything UI-related goes into a new Runnable that you call `runOnUiThread` on.